# Drawing a colored mesh in CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

In CGAL have a `Surface_mesh<Point_3>` with `Surface_mesh::Property_map<Surface_mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color>`. I use `CGAL::draw()` method to draw this mesh, however the different colors of faces don't reflect. What am I missing?

Comment: As an absolute _minimum_, you should show relevant code and your program's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of basic viewer of Surface mesh does not take into account the color of faces.

However, it is easy to change the code.

1. Have a look to the file [draw_surface_mesh.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Surface_mesh/include/CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h).
2. Add a functor MyColorFunctorSM (inspired by the existing DefaultColorFunctorSM) that returns the color of a face given its index
3. Replace in the draw function DefaultColorFunctorSM by your new functor MyColorFunctorSM.

(If you don't want to modity the CGAL file, you can define your functor in your code, and copy/paste the draw function in your code before to modify it).

Comment: Because three years have passed, I can't be sure that we're looking at the same file. It seems to me that they have effectively done what you suggested in draw_surface_mesh.h, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must hit the `M` key once in the viewer, to activate the 'multicolor' feature.

Comment: Thanks. This will be helpful to activate the colored view, but currently this just randomly colors my triangles and not the color I have assigned them in color map.

Comment: Ok, I thought it might work as I tried it on a colored cube and it seemd OK, but then it's @gdamiand who'se right, it is just not possible.

Comment: In 2023, this was the only reason my color scheme wasn't showing. The draw_surface_mesh.h file now has a color-aware functor in it.